# Finding a substring and inserting another string

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose I have string variable such as:

```
var a = "xxxxxxxxhelloxxxxxxxx";
```

or:

```
var a = "xxxxhelloxxxx";
```

I want to insert `"world"` after `"hello"`.

I can't use `substr()` because the position is not known ahead of time. How can I do this in JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```js
var a = "xxxxhelloxxxxhelloxxxx";
a = a.replace(/hello/g,"hello world"); // if you want all the "hello"'s in the string to be replaced
document.getElementById("regex").textContent = a;

a = "xxxxhelloxxxxhelloxxxx";
a = a.replace("hello","hello world"); // if you want only the first occurrence of "hello" to be replaced
document.getElementById("string").textContent = a;
```

```html
<p>With regex: <strong id="regex"></strong></p>
<p>With string: <strong id="string"></strong></p>
```

Comment: Replace returns a new string, so you'll need to assign it back to a

Comment: This method is genious!!. It actually removes the "hello" string. That is why in the second parameter inside a function written a "hello world" instead of " world".

Answer (score 9):

This will replace the first occurrence

```
a = a.replace("hello", "helloworld");
```

If you need to replace all of the occurrences, you'll need a regular expression. (The `g` flag at the end means "global", so it will find all occurences.)

```
a = a.replace(/hello/g, "helloworld");
```

Answer (score 5):

This will replace the first occurance:

```
a = a.replace("hello", "hello world");
```

If you need to replace all occurances, you use a regular expression for the match, and use the global (g) flag:

```
a = a.replace(/hello/g, "hello world");
```

Comment: @user2072826: Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways to [avoid repeating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) the pattern:

```
 a_new = a.replace(/hello/, '$& world');   // "xxxxxxxxhello worldxxxxxxxx"
```

`$&` represents the substring that matched the whole pattern. It is a [special code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description) for use in the replacement string.

```
a_new = a.replace(/hello/, function (match) { 
    return match + ' world'; 
});
```

A [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) is passed the same substring that matched the whole pattern.

Answer (score 3):

```
var find = "hello";

var a = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxhelloxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var i = a.indexOf(find);

var result = a.substr(0, i+find.length) + "world" + a.substr(i+find.length);

alert(result); //xxxxxxxxxxxxxhelloworldxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Maybe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace, would be much easier than indexOf

```
var newstring = a.replace("hello", "hello world");
```